# Advanced Vimeo API and XML Output

Tags: xml, api, vimeo

I am trying to output the XML to a FORM text area, but for some reason the content does not display.

```
http://pastebin.com/4DHNAw9W
```

File included at the top - vimeo.php.

```
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib/blob/master/vimeo.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default vimeo php library assumes that you don't care what the response type is. It automatically uses the PHP format, and will unserialize the data at the end.

So when you call

```
$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getAll', array('full_response' => '1','summary_response' => '1'));
```

The $videos variable will already be an object ready to use.

If you change the format, the library will still attempt to unserialize the data anyway, and fail on any non-php format.

If you want to use XML, you will need to remove the [unserialize](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib/blob/master/vimeo.php#L234) function from the library and make the request below (with format => xml)

```
$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getAll', array('format' => 'xml', 'full_response' => '1','summary_response' => '1'));
```

Comment: Thanks - the Vimeo support staff walked me through this and they did provided the same answer! Thanks for looking into this!